# Ant script : C:\Program is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: xml, cmd, ant

I am running ant script in which had property *devenv2005*.

```
<property name="devenv2005" value="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe&quot;"/>
```

Getting *'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command* error in below script execution where it had arg line using *devenv2005* property value

```
<target name="build-devenv2005">
    <exec executable="cmd.exe" failonerror="Yes">
        <arg line="/c ${devenv2005} /project ${project.name} ${sln.file.dir}\${project.name}.sln /out ${logfile} /rebuild ${config.type} /X"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

I already tried including double quotes in different ways for *devenv2005* property value. Can anyone please let me know what could be the issue?

Comment: Try adding the `/S` option in `<arg line="/S /C ${devenv2005} …"/>`; alternatively, tzry adding quotes herein like `<arg line="/C &quot;${devenv2005}&quot; …"/>`…

Comment: @KJ, it is resolving the issue with console open to see command as mentioned. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /project migration ..\launcher\migration.sln /out .\mlauncher-build.log /rebuild Release. Later it is failing to find release folder